# HTML navbar not changing background color upon hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm attempting to re-create this [navbar](https://codepen.io/ettrics/pen/WRbGRN) on my local machine. I have the relevant html/css/js loaded correctly, including jquery, the only issue is when I hover over each element, the element background is not changing to the color blue.

I've tried re-arranging the order of my js/css in the head section, but there's no change.

For a reproducible example, here is the html:

```js
class StickyNavigation {

  constructor() {
    this.currentId = null;
    this.currentTab = null;
    this.tabContainerHeight = 70;
    let self = this;
    $('.et-hero-tab').click(function() {
      self.onTabClick(event, $(this));
    });
    $(window).scroll(() => {
      this.onScroll();
    });
    $(window).resize(() => {
      this.onResize();
    });
  }

  onTabClick(event, element) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let scrollTop = $(element.attr('href')).offset().top - this.tabContainerHeight + 1;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: scrollTop
    }, 600);
  }

  onScroll() {
    this.checkTabContainerPosition();
    this.findCurrentTabSelector();
  }

  onResize() {
    if (this.currentId) {
      this.setSliderCss();
    }
  }

  checkTabContainerPosition() {
    let offset = $('.et-hero-tabs').offset().top + $('.et-hero-tabs').height() - this.tabContainerHeight;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset) {
      $('.et-hero-tabs-container').addClass('et-hero-tabs-container--top');
    } else {
      $('.et-hero-tabs-container').removeClass('et-hero-tabs-container--top');
    }
  }

  findCurrentTabSelector(element) {
    let newCurrentId;
    let newCurrentTab;
    let self = this;
    $('.et-hero-tab').each(function() {
      let id = $(this).attr('href');
      let offsetTop = $(id).offset().top - self.tabContainerHeight;
      let offsetBottom = $(id).offset().top + $(id).height() - self.tabContainerHeight;
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > offsetTop && $(window).scrollTop() < offsetBottom) {
        newCurrentId = id;
        newCurrentTab = $(this);
      }
    });
    if (this.currentId != newCurrentId || this.currentId === null) {
      this.currentId = newCurrentId;
      this.currentTab = newCurrentTab;
      this.setSliderCss();
    }
  }

  setSliderCss() {
    let width = 0;
    let left = 0;
    if (this.currentTab) {
      width = this.currentTab.css('width');
      left = this.currentTab.offset().left;
    }
    $('.et-hero-tab-slider').css('width', width);
    $('.et-hero-tab-slider').css('left', left);
  }

}

new StickyNavigation();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.et-hero-tabs,
.et-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2em;
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1rem;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
}

.et-hero-tabs-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  &--top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
}

.et-hero-tab {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  color: #FF0000;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  &:hover {
    color: #FF0000;
    background: rgba(102, 177, 241, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
}

.et-hero-tab-slider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  background: #66B1F1;
  transition: left 0.3s ease;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .et-hero-tabs,
  .et-slide {
    h1 {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
    h3 {
      font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }
  .et-hero-tab {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Hero -->
<section class="et-hero-tabs">
  <h1>STICKY SLIDER NAV</h1>
  <h3>Sliding content with sticky tab nav</h3>
  <div class="et-hero-tabs-container">
    <a class="et-hero-tab" href="#tab-es6">ES6</a>
    <a class="et-hero-tab" href="#tab-flexbox">Flexbox</a>
    <a class="et-hero-tab" href="#tab-react">React</a>
    <a class="et-hero-tab" href="#tab-angular">Angular</a>
    <a class="et-hero-tab" href="#tab-other">Other</a>
    <span class="et-hero-tab-slider"></span>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Main -->
<main class="et-main">
  <section class="et-slide" id="tab-es6">
    <h1>ES6</h1>
    <h3>something about es6</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="et-slide" id="tab-flexbox">
    <h1>Flexbox</h1>
    <h3>something about flexbox</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="et-slide" id="tab-react">
    <h1>React</h1>
    <h3>something about react</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="et-slide" id="tab-angular">
    <h1>Angular</h1>
    <h3>something about angular</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="et-slide" id="tab-other">
    <h1>Other</h1>
    <h3>something about other</h3>
  </section>
</main>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's useful in this sort of case to use your browser's dev tools inspect facility. Running your snippet and inspecting one of the links many of the CSS settings have yellow warning triangles beside them and are corssed out as not being recognisable as CSS e.g. use of the & which looks more like SCSS than pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it cannot work because you are not using SCSS, you are using css and it does not support nested syntax like:

```
.et-hero-tab {
  ...
  &:hover {
    color: #FF0000;
    background: rgba(102, 177, 241, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
}
```

change the styles of hover to:

```
  .et-hero-tab:hover {
    color: #FF0000;
    background: rgba(102, 177, 241, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the SCSS syntax to plain CSS syntax as changed below

```js
class StickyNavigation {

  constructor() {
    this.currentId = null;
    this.currentTab = null;
    this.tabContainerHeight = 70;
    let self = this;
    $('.et-hero-tab').click(function() {
      self.onTabClick(event, $(this));
    });
    $(window).scroll(() => {
      this.onScroll();
    });
    $(window).resize(() => {
      this.onResize();
    });
  }

  onTabClick(event, element) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let scrollTop = $(element.attr('href')).offset().top - this.tabContainerHeight + 1;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: scrollTop
    }, 600);
  }

  onScroll() {
    this.checkTabContainerPosition();
    this.findCurrentTabSelector();
  }

  onResize() {
    if (this.currentId) {
      this.setSliderCss();
    }
  }

  checkTabContainerPosition() {
    let offset = $('.et-hero-tabs').offset().top + $('.et-hero-tabs').height() - this.tabContainerHeight;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset) {
      $('.et-hero-tabs-container').addClass('et-hero-tabs-container--top');
    } else {
      $('.et-hero-tabs-container').removeClass('et-hero-tabs-container--top');
    }
  }

  findCurrentTabSelector(element) {
    let newCurrentId;
    let newCurrentTab;
    let self = this;
    $('.et-hero-tab').each(function() {
      let id = $(this).attr('href');
      let offsetTop = $(id).offset().top - self.tabContainerHeight;
      let offsetBottom = $(id).offset().top + $(id).height() - self.tabContainerHeight;
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > offsetTop && $(window).scrollTop() < offsetBottom) {
        newCurrentId = id;
        newCurrentTab = $(this);
      }
    });
    if (this.currentId != newCurrentId || this.currentId === null) {
      this.currentId = newCurrentId;
      this.currentTab = newCurrentTab;
      this.setSliderCss();
    }
  }

  setSliderCss() {
    let width = 0;
    let left = 0;
    if (this.currentTab) {
      width = this.currentTab.css('width');
      left = this.currentTab.offset().left;
    }
    $('.et-hero-tab-slider').css('width', width);
    $('.et-hero-tab-slider').css('left', left);
  }

}

new StickyNavigation();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.et-hero-tabs,
.et-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

.et-hero-tabs h1,
.et-slide h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 1rem;
}

.et-hero-tabs h3,
.et-slide h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.et-hero-tabs-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

.et-hero-tabs-container--top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.et-hero-tab {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  color: #FF0000;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.et-hero-tab:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
  background: rgba(102, 177, 241, 0.8);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.et-hero-tab-slider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  background: #66B1F1;
  transition: left 0.3s ease;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .et-hero-tabs h1,
  .et-slide h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  .et-hero-tabs h3,
  .et-slide h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .et-hero-tab {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Hero -->
<section class="et-hero-tabs">
  <h1>STICKY SLIDER NAV</h1>
  <h3>Sliding content with sticky tab nav</h3>
  <div class="et-hero-tabs-container">
    <a class="et-hero-tab" href="#tab-es6">ES6</a>
    <a class="et-hero-tab" href="#tab-flexbox">Flexbox</a>
    <a class="et-hero-tab" href="#tab-react">React</a>
    <a class="et-hero-tab" href="#tab-angular">Angular</a>
    <a class="et-hero-tab" href="#tab-other">Other</a>
    <span class="et-hero-tab-slider"></span>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Main -->
<main class="et-main">
  <section class="et-slide" id="tab-es6">
    <h1>ES6</h1>
    <h3>something about es6</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="et-slide" id="tab-flexbox">
    <h1>Flexbox</h1>
    <h3>something about flexbox</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="et-slide" id="tab-react">
    <h1>React</h1>
    <h3>something about react</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="et-slide" id="tab-angular">
    <h1>Angular</h1>
    <h3>something about angular</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="et-slide" id="tab-other">
    <h1>Other</h1>
    <h3>something about other</h3>
  </section>
</main>
```